# Different output when set different breakpoints

Tags: c++, heap

I just wrote a code to build a Huffman Tree using MinHeap. When testing I want to output its traversal result.

The algorithm is simple, but my code can't get the right answer. It's strange that the output was different when I set different breakpoints. For instance, it depends on if I set a break point in the loop, such as line 165 `input_list.insert(*parent);`.

The test input was

```
4 //number of nodes.
1 1 3 5 //weight of each node.
```

and the output when debugging it with a breakpoint in the loop is

```
5
10
1
2
1
5
3
```

that is correct. But when I just run it without debug, it even didn't have any output. Does anyone know how to explain it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define max_size 100

int sum=0;

class huffman_node
{
public:
    int weight;
    huffman_node* left_child;
    huffman_node* right_child;

    huffman_node(){}

    huffman_node(int w, huffman_node* l, huffman_node* r):
        weight(w),left_child(l),right_child(r) {}

};

vector <huffman_node> node_list;

class minheap
{
public:
    minheap()
    {
        heap=new huffman_node [max_size];
        current_size=0;
    }

    ~minheap()
    {
        delete []heap;
    }

    void siftdown(int start, int m)
    {
        int i=start;
        int j=2*i+1;
        huffman_node temp=heap[i];

        while(j<=m)
        {
            if(j<m && heap[j+1].weight<heap[j].weight)
            {
                ++j;
            }
            if(temp.weight<=heap[j].weight)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                heap[i]=heap[j];
                i=j;
                j=2*i+1;
            }
        }
        heap[i]=temp;
    }

    void siftup(int start)
    {
        int j=start;
        int i=(j-1)/2;
        huffman_node temp=heap[j];

        while(j>0)
        {
            if(heap[i].weight<=temp.weight)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                heap[j]=heap[i];
                j=i;
                i=(j-1)/2;
            }
            heap[j]=temp;
        }
    }

    bool insert(const huffman_node& input)
    {
        if(current_size==max_size)
        {
            cout<<"minheap full"<<endl;
            return false;
        }
        heap[current_size]=input;
        siftup(current_size);
        ++current_size;
        return true;
    }

    bool remove_min(huffman_node& output)
    {
        if(!current_size)
        {
            cout<<"minheap empty"<<endl;
            return false;
        }
        output=heap[0];
        heap[0]=heap[current_size-1];
        --current_size;
        siftdown(0,current_size-1);
        return true;
    }

private:
    huffman_node* heap;
    int current_size;
};

void route_length(huffman_node* &root,int depth)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
//        if(root->left_child==NULL&&root->right_child==NULL)
//        {
//            sum+=depth*root->weight;

//        }
        route_length(root->left_child,depth+1);
        cout<<root->weight<<endl;
        route_length(root->right_child,depth+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    minheap input_list;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        int key;
        cin>>key;
        huffman_node input(key,NULL,NULL);
        input_list.insert(input);
        cin.get();
    }

    huffman_node* root;

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;++i)
    {
        huffman_node* parent;
        huffman_node out1;
        huffman_node out2;
        input_list.remove_min(out1);
        input_list.remove_min(out2);
        node_list.push_back(out1);
        node_list.push_back(out2);
        parent=new huffman_node(out1.weight+out2.weight,&node_list[node_list.size()-2],&node_list[node_list.size()-1]);
        input_list.insert(*parent);
        root=parent;
    }
    route_length(root,0);
//    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I copy pasted it and got an access violation. You might be suffering from UB that either is affected by the IDE's breakpoints, or coincidentally happens when you set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using pointers to elements of a `vector<huffman_node>` and storing these in your data structure (i.e. left and right members of the `huffman_node` object).

The thing that is randomly killing your program is that `std::vector` moves values around in memory when you append to it. The contents of the elements of the vectors are preserved, but the location is not. Once it moves the elements, the memory where the vector used to be can be overwritten by whatever (i.e. gdb needs heap memory too) and now the pointers are pointing to garbage.

As a quick sanity check, you can make your code not crash by reserving space in your `node_list` by calling

```
node_list.reserve(max_size*2);
```

in the beginning of `main`. This is not the right way of developing this piece of code further, but should illustrate the problem.

It would be better if your `node_list` was a `vector<huffman_node*>` instead. Or if you changed the left/right members to be vector indices instead of pointers.